# SpriteKit Swift3 touched SKNode

Tags: compiler-errors, swift3, sprite-kit, touch, 2d

I'm trying to get condition of touched location in SceneKit. I'm touching SpriteKit objects and wrote that code to get SKnode object:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController , SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

var overlay: SKScene!

...

override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent!) {

   for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location: CGPoint  = touch.location(in: overlay)
        let touchedNode: SKNode = overlay.nodes(at: location

        if(touchedNode.name == "WalkAnimationButton") {

            self.tap()
        }
        else if(touchedNode.name == "CameraButton") {

            sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        }
        else if(touchedNode.name == "WrenchButton") {

            sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        }
        else if(touchedNode.name == "CharacterButton") {
            if(currentCharacter < characterPaths.count-1) {
                currentCharacter = currentCharacter+1
            }
            else{
                currentCharacter = 0
            }
        }

    }

    self.setCharacterFromModelWithName(name: characterPaths[currentCharacter] as! NSString)
}
```

Xcode wrote that error which i've never faced before:
**Cannot convert value of type '[SKNode]' to specified type 'SKNode'**

Comment: Looks like overlay.nodes(...) returns an array, and you are attempting to assign the array (of nodes) to a node.

Comment: Omg. Thanks. let touchedNode: SKNode = overlay.atPoint(location)
works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To call the touched node we should use that code:

```
let touchedNode: SKNode = overlay.atPoint(location)
```

Because we calling **name** of SpriteKit object, which is using as member of SKNode class.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43320425/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply.